# My path breadcrumbs are in an overridden state

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, breadcrumbs

Yesterday I installed [Path Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs) module and created some breadcrumbs rules. I featured them and then I didn't work with them.
Today I opened breadcrumbs on my local site and saw "Overridden" near the names of every breadcrumb rules. Feature is not in overridden state. I re-saved breadcrumbs, but nothing happened.
What can it be and why? How to fix it?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPddw.png

Comment: First of all, try using [Diff](https://www.drupal.org/project/diff) module to see what exactly is overridden. To access the diff report, navigate to `admin/structure/features` and check the State.

Comment: @halfzebra but this Diff module is for features, not for breadcrumbs